# How to display another canvas without zoom in fabricjs

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

In short, I am developing a project in which there are two canvases: a canvas that supports zoom and drawing, a second canvas - a duplicate of the first canvas, which should display a general view without zoom. Unfortunately, I do not understand how to implement this, since the second canvas also displays a picture with a zoom. Please, help!
Here is a small example of what I have:

```js
var c1 = document.getElementById("scale");
var c2 = document.getElementById("static");

var canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas(c1, {
  isDrawingMode: true
});
var ctx1 = c1.getContext("2d");
var ctx2 = c2.getContext("2d");

function copy() {
    var imgData = ctx1.getImageData(0, 0, 512, 512);
    ctx2.putImageData(imgData, 0, 0);
}

fabric.Image.fromURL(
  "https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1800/1*sg-uLNm73whmdOgKlrQdZA.jpeg",
  img => {
    img.scaleToWidth(canvas.width);
    canvas.setBackgroundImage(img);
    canvas.requestRenderAll();
  },
  {
    crossOrigin: "Annoymous"
  }
);

canvas.on('mouse:wheel', function(opt) {
  var delta = opt.e.deltaY;
  var pointer = canvas.getPointer(opt.e);
  var zoom = canvas.getZoom();
  zoom = zoom + delta/200;
  if (zoom > 20) zoom = 20;
  if (zoom < 0.01) zoom = 0.01;
  canvas.zoomToPoint({ x: opt.e.offsetX, y: opt.e.offsetY }, zoom);
  opt.e.preventDefault();
  opt.e.stopPropagation();
});
    

setInterval(() => {
    copy();
}, 10)
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#static {
  position: relative;
  top: -300px;
  left: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/3.6.1/fabric.min.js"> </script>

This is interactive canvas
<canvas id="scale" width="300" height="300"></canvas>

<canvas id="static"width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not a perfect solution because fabricJS does not support rendering on more targets.

There is a toCanvasElement method here that creates a copy to another canvas, but it does not let you specify the canvas you want to draw on.

So here what i m doing is, at some point:

- reset the zoom to 1
- render to a new canvas
- put back the zoom to what it was
- copy that canvas on the static canvas

There is an extra copy, that is fast on modern hardware, to the point that you do not care, but would be nicer to add a canvas argument to that toCanvasElement method in order to get the drawing happening on the specified canvas immediately

Then apart from that there is the quesiton on when firing that copy.
'after:render' is not a great idea, it will loop forever and it will also redraw on zoom changes, that is not what you want.

For now i use object:added, you can add also object:modified, and maybe something else but ideally you will call a copy manually when needed when you run some code that will change some of the drawing properties.

```js
var c1 = document.getElementById("scale");
var c2 = document.getElementById("static");

var canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas(c1, {
  isDrawingMode: true
});
var ctx2 = c2.getContext("2d");

function copy(copiedCanvas) {
   ctx2.drawImage(copiedCanvas,0,0);
}

fabric.Image.fromURL(
  "https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1800/1*sg-uLNm73whmdOgKlrQdZA.jpeg",
  img => {
    img.scaleToWidth(canvas.width);
    canvas.setBackgroundImage(img);
    canvas.requestRenderAll();
  },
  {
    crossOrigin: "Annoymous"
  }
);

canvas.on('mouse:wheel', function(opt) {
  var delta = opt.e.deltaY;
  var pointer = canvas.getPointer(opt.e);
  var zoom = canvas.getZoom();
  zoom = zoom + delta/200;
  if (zoom > 20) zoom = 20;
  if (zoom < 0.01) zoom = 0.01;
  canvas.zoomToPoint({ x: opt.e.offsetX, y: opt.e.offsetY }, zoom);
  opt.e.preventDefault();
  opt.e.stopPropagation();
});

function afterRender() {
  var originalVP = canvas.viewportTransform;
  canvas.viewportTransform = [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0];
  copy(canvas.toCanvasElement());
  canvas.viewportTransform = originalVP;
}

canvas.on('object:added', afterRender);
canvas.on('object:modified', afterRender);
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#static {
  position: relative;
  top: -300px;
  left: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/3.6.1/fabric.min.js"> </script>

This is interactive canvas
<canvas id="scale" width="300" height="300"></canvas>

<canvas id="static"width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```

Comment: sorry but i find a little bug. Left canvas order are not match to the right canvas. 
Please, look at this [picture](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AqtIFlFVWz4MhN8azrICsS0qMKqltw?e=gXisdz)
My [codepen](https://codepen.io/vinar22/pen/XWJLrwv)

Comment: that is because you are using the preserveObjectStacking false. The object that goes on top when you select is not available during export. This would be the same for the other solution.

Comment: So, if I use * preseveObjectStacking: true * and manually send the object to the front, will this work?

Comment: yes, but i would not suggest it. An object is UP to get better visualization of what are you doing with it ( scaling/moving) but the design on the right represent the general situation of the left canvas, and that object should be in the right position in the stack. Those are UX OPINIONS and as such should be taken. The app is your and you do it as you want.

Comment: Oh, ok. Thank you again!

Comment: Andrea, could you explain one question to me? Why can't I pass the getImageData function in the same way after viewportTransform as I did it with `toCanvasElement`? Please, look at this [codepen](https://codepen.io/vinar22/pen/XWJLrwv) I want to do it like this because i have bad perfomance with a large number of objects

Comment: I tried to replace the toCanvasElement function with toDataURL . Performance is much better at scaling object and zooming canvas, but by moving object it`s still bad. You can look it [here](https://codepen.io/vinar22/pen/gOpYQMw?editors=1010) The problem works if you select spray brush and after drawing and zooming canvas, try to move the line. So its will be cool if i could put image data from canvas before rendering to another canvas without using "slow functions"

Comment: Hello, @AndreaBogazzi, I tried to play with `after:render` and `before:render`, this works, but only at the borders of the controls, please see [this](https://codepen.io/vinar22/pen/JjdjWYG) How i can resolve it?

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is that you are getting the "ImageData" from the context
but you should be using the `fabric.Canvas` object...

The context only gives you what you see, so those two canvases will be a mirror image, you have to get the data from the `fabric.Canvas` that is the one that has the "big picture" with all the edits.

In my prototype I'm using `canvas.toJSON` to get the data then to draw that data I use `loadFromJSON`, but I did notice some flickering the new image is loaded so I decided to use an image instead of the static canvas, that way the transition is seamless

see my simple prototype below:

```js
var c1 = document.getElementById("scale");
var static = document.getElementById("img");
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas(c1, {isDrawingMode: true});

function copy() {
  var data = canvas.toObject();
  var c = new fabric.Canvas();
  c.loadFromJSON(data,  function() {
    static.src = c.toDataURL({ format: 'png' });
  });  
}

fabric.Image.fromURL(
  "https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1800/1*sg-uLNm73whmdOgKlrQdZA.jpeg",
  img => {
    img.scaleToWidth(canvas.width);
    canvas.setBackgroundImage(img);
    canvas.requestRenderAll();
  }, { crossOrigin: "anonymous" }
);

canvas.on('mouse:wheel', function(opt) {
  var pointer = canvas.getPointer(opt.e);
  var zoom = canvas.getZoom() + opt.e.deltaY / 200;
  if (zoom > 20) zoom = 20;
  if (zoom < 0.01) zoom = 0.01;
  canvas.zoomToPoint({
    x: opt.e.offsetX,
    y: opt.e.offsetY
  }, zoom);
  opt.e.preventDefault();
  opt.e.stopPropagation();
});

setInterval(copy, 200)
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 2px solid black;
}
img {
  border: 2px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px; right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/3.6.1/fabric.min.js">
</script>

<canvas id="scale" width="300" height="150"></canvas>
<br><img id="img"   width="300" height="150">
```

Unless we get some browser compatibility issue (I only tested chrome), the result should look like:
[image]

Comment: Thanks so much, man! You made my day !! But does this method not affect performance?

Comment: I want to update the image more often and i passed 1ms in setinterval function. When you wait for a 2 minutes and move objects at this time, fabric canvas freezes and the screen goes black. Please, look this [codepen](https://codepen.io/vinar22/pen/XWJLrwv)

Comment: In the end i see this [picture](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AqtIFlFVWz4MhN8YSfKa91xj15R0fA?e=2vAKDP)

Comment: the `1ms in setinterval` is a bad bad BAD idea, maybe you can fire that `copy` only on some events from the `fabric.Canvas` check the documentation see if there is anything like onChange

Comment: Ok, i set canvas event `object:moving`. But is it possible to increase updating image?  It looks slow and i see delays. Another intersting moment, when i resize my canvas to 512x512px and set image to same options, [my image stretched out](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AqtIFlFVWz4MhN8ZpOY4XDygotya5w?e=ILsKx3).

Comment: Those are completely different questions... we could keep going on the comments forever about issues and optimization but that's not how stackoverflow should be used. You have to do your own research