# Save dataImage of canvas before rendering

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I am developing a project where I have two canvases. The first canvas supports scaling and drawing, the second canvas is a duplicate of the first canvas, which should display a general view of the first canvas without scaling. I already asked about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59989597/how-to-display-another-canvas-without-zoom-in-fabricjs/60025853?noredirect=1#comment106216624_60025853), and this what I [have](https://codepen.io/vinar22/pen/gOpYQMw?editors=1010) now. In this solution, I copy the state of the canvas before scaling using function `toDataURL`. But this is a very slow way and I get poor performance. I tried using `getImageData` instead and [got not what I expected](https://codepen.io/vinar22/pen/XWJLrwv). Also i tried to play with functions `after:render` and `before:render`, but without result, please, look [this](https://codepen.io/vinar22/pen/JjdjWYG). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's not clear what  you're trying to do. The last example appears to work as expected.

Comment: Hi! I want to see the second canvas without zoom as a general view of the first canvas. Please, look [this](https://codepen.io/vinar22/pen/gOpYQMw?editors=1010). I want the same, but using `getImageData` instead `toDataURL`

Comment: just to try to help, the answer you got here: `https://stackoverflow.com/a/60025853/2655678` toCanvasElement is the most performant you can get. All the other will rely in a way on the other on top of toCanvasElement doing more things. What is exactly missing there in order to be valuable?

Comment: Hi, @AndreaBogazzi ! This answer doesn’t quite suit me, because degrades  the performance of my application if there are too many objects on the canvas. As I understand it, the function `toCanvasElement` re-render canvas every time when i zoom it. Is there a way to not run the rendering at this moment?

Comment: No it rerender the canvas, every time you call it, and is the only way to get a copy of the canvas on a different zoom level. toCanvasElement is the fastest way you have in fabric to get a different viewport of your canvas. Whatever else you use is using toCanvasElement + additional work.

Comment: Every re-render at different scale will slow down with many objects if you do not turn off caching.

Comment: Ok, i understand. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Fabric.js scales its canvas up if [devicePixelRatio](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/devicePixelRatio) is > 1. That's why you're getting a 'zoomed' picture when you draw pixels obtained from `getImageData()`. A better way would be to use `drawImage()` and supply it the destination width/height so that your browser decides if it should scale those pixels down or up according to the source image dimensions.

2) You're right about resetting viewport transform but it's not enough - you should apply this new transform and re-render the canvas somehow. That's what Fabric.js does when you call `toDataURL()` - it invokes `toCanvasElement()`, which makes a copy of canvas and renders all objects on it. Your implementation should mirror this logic.

The solution below introduces `drawOnCopyCanvas()` method, which is a patched version of `toCanvasElement()`. It doesn't use an intermediate canvas and draws directly on a supplied canvas instead.

```
fabric.StaticCanvas.prototype.drawCopyOnCanvas = function(canvasEl) {
  // save values
  var scaledWidth = this.width,
      scaledHeight = this.height,
      vp = this.viewportTransform,
      originalInteractive = this.interactive,
      newVp = [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
      originalRetina = this.enableRetinaScaling,
      originalContextTop = this.contextTop;
  // reset
  this.contextTop = null;
  this.enableRetinaScaling = false;
  this.interactive = false;
  this.viewportTransform = newVp;
  this.calcViewportBoundaries();
  // draw on copy
  this.renderCanvas(canvasEl.getContext('2d'), this._objects);
  // restore values
  this.viewportTransform = vp;
  this.calcViewportBoundaries();
  this.interactive = originalInteractive;
  this.enableRetinaScaling = originalRetina;
  this.contextTop = originalContextTop;
}

function afterRender() {
  // remove 'after:render' listener as canvas.toCanvasElement()
  // calls renderCanvas(), which results in an infinite recursion
  canvas.off('after:render', afterRender);
  // draw c1 contents on c2
  canvas.drawCopyOnCanvas(c2);
  setTimeout(() => {
    // re-attach the listener in the next event loop
    canvas.on('after:render', afterRender);
  });
}

canvas.on('after:render', afterRender);
```

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the response. Is there a way without using the toCanvasElement or toDataUrl function? I got poor performance if I render a large number of objects. Try using the spray brush [here](https://codepen.io/vinar22/pen/BaNNGMK) to understand what I'm talking about.

Comment: @ArkadiyVinkovskiy You can take a look at what toCanvasElement() does under the hood to try and cut some corners - you mostly need the part where it makes a blank canvas and renders all objects on it with the new viewport transform applied. Other than that - maybe try to profile the script and look for the bottlenecks, whether it's fabric.js code or drawing/pixel manipulation.

Comment: @ArkadiyVinkovskiy btw, if you're wondering about the `drawImage()` vs `putImageData()` performance - some tests suggest drawImage is the winner. https://jsperf.com/canvas-drawimage-vs-putimagedata/106

Comment: Now that I think about it, there is no reason to make a whole new canvas just to copy its contents to the third one. I'll update my answer.

Comment: thank you. This way looks more minimalistic. But unfortunately, [this](https://codepen.io/vinar22/pen/BaNNGMK) is not improve the perfomance. Is it possible not re-render canvas every time?

Comment: @ArkadiyVinkovskiy it might be possible but I can't think of any way that would potentially perform better. Script profiling might give you some ideas though.